# Python: Can autocomplete be used for the elements in a list?

Tags: python, autocomplete, type-hinting

Python has type hints in function arguments and function return types. Is there something similar for elements of a class? I would like to be able to use autocomplete in something like the following example:

```
class MyClass:
    def hello(self):
        print("Hello")

mylist = []
mylist.append(MyClass())

for i in mylist:
    i.hello() # No autocomplete here
```

I understand this depends on the IDE but my question is about some language feature like the code hints mentioned above. Something like mylist = [] : MyClass or similar

Comment: It depends on the IDE (which one  are we talking about?) but the IDE cannot generally know if you have only one type of object inside your list or not.

Comment: No, there are no generics in Python as it is not statically typed. You can always have different types of objects in the same collection.

Comment: I know you can. You can also pass any object as a parameter even if you use the func(a: int) syntax, but it is still useful as a guide for the programmer and the IDE.

Comment: Yes, function annotations are for documentation purposes only.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes it can. This works in WingIDE (and I'm sure in PyCharm as well):

```
from typing import List

class MyClass:
    def hello(self):
        print("Hello")

mylist: List[MyClass] = []
mylist.append(MyClass())

for i in mylist:
    i.hello() # autocompleted here
```

If you use python before version 3.6, just use the old style syntax:

```
mylist = []  # type: List[MyClass]
```

The auto-completion works fine with either syntax.